# How to parse html from some special html tag?

Tags: html, reactjs

I create a test html string and try to render it in React, but my solution is not working.

Try the solution1:

```
const textHtml = '<p>Test</p><p><strong>Test</strong></p><p><em>Test</em></p>';

return (
  <div>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: textHtml }} />
  </div>
);
```

Try the solution 2, install html package:

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

const textHtml = '<p>Test</p><p><strong>Test</strong></p><p><em>Test</em></p>';

return (
  <div>
    <div>{parse(textHtml)}</div>
  </div>
);
```

`em` and `strong` tags are not working both of the solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a React/html issue, you likely have some CSS overriding  and  tags. First solution should work just fine.

Comment: but like `<p><strong>Test</strong></p>`, strong not working. Is any trick way I have to achieve ?

Comment: I copied your example and everything works fine. Check if the issue can be something else and not that part of the code. Do tags get rendered ?

Comment: I use Nextjs for React, may be the issue comes from Nextjs ?

Comment: Yes, I found my problem comes from reset css file, thanks for your help.